# Why isn't Cloud Run sending cookies?

Tags: express, cookies, google-cloud-run, fastify

I have a fastify server that serves cookies to maintain the session.

When I test on localhost, it works as expected. I get a cookie on localhost:3000.

When I host my server as a container image through Cloud Run, however, I can not see any cookies inside the route. I can see the request has a cookie when it's sent to the server, but it's not being parsed. This is causing my session to create a new session and I can't get any context.

Are there any special considerations regarding Cloud Run and cookies?

Comment: I'm not sure on my assumption, but because the traffic is not direct from Internet to your Cloud Run service (there is a proxy in the middle) it's possible that the proxy doesn't forward the cookies to the Cloud Run service. I find that strange but it's not impossible. Maybe another expert could confirm that.

Comment: It would be useful for you to log the (cookie) headers on requests received by your fastify app and to then use `curl` or equivalent to emphatically submit a request that includes cookies to the service. Are cookies being persisted by the browser? Do these match the Cloud Run service's domain?

Comment: The cookies are an empty array in fastify. No cookies in the headers either. Could something be stripping it?

Answer (score 4):

1. Only If you are using Firebase Hosting + Cloud Run, `__session` is the only cookie you can store, by design.
   This is necessary for Google to be able to efficiently cache content on the CDN -- Google strips all cookies from the request other than `__session`.
   This is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#using_cookies).

2. If you are using Load Balancer, or other means like custom domains to connect to your Cloud Run service, there is no restriction on cookies, and you get all.